# PySimpleGUI: How is window.read() related to updating a window or element?

Tags: pysimplegui

I have a windows that is basically a `Graph` which shows a camera image with some overlay drawn upon.

While trying to clean up the code to OOP style I came across the issue that some elements are not drawn or updated anymore. I know this is caused by how the updated is located relative to `window.read()` but I could not figure out the correct way to make it work.

So far the code looks like

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

while True:

    gui.window['-MAIN-'].draw_text('some_text', (80, 15), color='black')

    event, values = gui.update()

    if event == 'Exit' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    gui.window['-PAUSE-'].update(f'Paused')

    gui.window['-MAIN-'].erase()

    gui.window['-MAIN-'].draw_image(data=some_bytes)
```

The things I use are

- erasing the main component `Graph.erase()`
- changing labels using `element.update()`
- drawing on a graph `element.draw_image()`

From what I read in the documentation I assume that updates ti elements that are made using `element.update()` are applied once `window.read()` is called.
Is that correct?

And is it the same for `element.draw_image()` and `Graph.erase()`?

Because I am not sure how that works exactly I don't know what would be a good way to order things in the main loop.

From the examples in the cookbook I saw that the first thing that is usually placed in the event look is the call to `window.read()`.

But what would be a good place for `Graph.erase()`? Before or after `window.read()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define layout and your window, GUI won't be created if window not yet finalized by option `finalize=True` or method `finalize` called.

After window or GUI finalized, you can do something on window or elements, like call `update` of elements, draw or erase figures on `sg.Canvas`, all of these actions just update window or elements, not really on GUI.

Two methods will update GUI, `sg.Window.read` or `sg.Window.refresh`.

Call `refresh` if you want update GUI immediately, or call `read` before your GUI ready to response any events from keyboard/mouse or else.

Most of time, first statement in your event loop is `event, values = window.read()`, then do something for which event happened.